# JTabbedPane setTabComponent

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Honestly not sure if I've found a bug or there's something wrong with my code.  I'm trying to implement some JTabbedPane tabs for a simple web browser implementation. The Java reference seems simple enough but I get erratic behavior; the tabs will not close with the jtabbedpane.remove(index) call.

We want the behavior to be like the second example in this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

The call jtabbedpane.remove(index) fails and the number of tabs does not sync; I close one and the count remains the same.  I'm not sure where the validation is supposed to be in the Java code.

This is a personal project, not work.

```
public class CustomJButton___CloseTabJButton extends JButton
{
    public Integer index;

    public CustomActionListener listener = new CustomActionListener();

    public CustomJButton___CloseTabJButton()
    {
        this.addActionListener(listener);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(17,17));

        setToolTipText("Close this tab");

        setContentAreaFilled(false);


    }

    //paint the cross
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        //shift the image for pressed buttons
        if (getModel().isPressed()) {
            g2.translate(1, 1);
        }
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        }
        int delta = 6;
        g2.drawLine(delta, delta, getWidth() - delta - 1, getHeight() - delta - 1);
        g2.drawLine(getWidth() - delta - 1, delta, delta, getHeight() - delta - 1);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
            CustomJTabbedPane jtabbedpane = (CustomJTabbedPane) Bodhi.pull(new Name("//jtabbedpane"));

            int closureindex = jtabbedpane.indexOfTabComponent(CustomJButton___CloseTabJButton.this);

            int selectedtabindex = jtabbedpane.getSelectedIndex();

            int tabcount = jtabbedpane.getTabCount();

            //int tabcount2 = jtabbedpane.getTabRunCount();

            System.out.println("ClosureIndex "+closureindex);

            System.out.println("SelectedTabIndex "+selectedtabindex);

            //System.out.println("Tabcount 2"+tabcount2+"\n");

            if(closureindex != -1)
            {
                jtabbedpane.setSelectedIndex(closureindex);

                jtabbedpane.removeTabAt(closureindex);

                jtabbedpane.invalidate();

                jtabbedpane.revalidate();

                System.out.println("Tabcount "+tabcount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *We want the behavior to be like the second example in this link:* - well that example works for me. So your custom code is causing the problem. Start with the working example. Make a simple change and then retest. Then make another simple change and retest. *I'm not sure where the validation is supposed* - does the working example do a validation? I don't see it anywhere, so I'm not sure why you think you need to do anything special. All you need to do is invoke the `remove(…)` method of the JTabbedPane, like the example does. Don't know why your code is so different than the working code.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking.  I run the debugger on it and it goes to the remove(...) call but it just doesn't remove the tab.  I really need a strong Java UI person to look at it.

Comment: As I already suggested you start with working code and make a small change and then retest, so you can isolate where the problem is. This is basic debugging.  I have no ideas why you made the changes you did.

Comment: I copy pasted the code exactly.   I still have the rightmost tab doing nothing when it should close by clicking on the x button.

Comment: Your code is using a `CustomTabbedPane` class. The problem could be there. We are not here to debug your code. I have already suggest twice you start with working code!!! Change one line at a time and see if it still works. Then make another change and keep repeating. We have no idea why you are changing working code or what you expect it do to. The code you posted is of no help. We can't compile and execute that code.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I've still got the bug.  Even with a simple JTabbedPane the rightmost tab just doesn't close.

Comment: Once again the point is to START with the working example from the tutorial. If you need to make changes you change one or two lines of code and then retest. This is basic debugging to determine what change is causing the error. Then can ask a specific question. You have done nothing to improve your question.